# Pop-up a print dialog box is no function

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the PHP and javascript to do the pop-up a print dialog box but doesn't work for me. Below is my code:

`Frontend`

```html
<a id="btn_cetak" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="printfolder()">Cetak</a>

<script style="text/javascript">
function printfolder(){
    var action = 'print_file';
    var loc = getQueryVariable('loc');
    $.ajax({
        
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?f=' + loc,
        data: { 
                action: action,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var myWindow = window.open("","","width=900,height=700");
            myWindow.document.write(data);
            
        },
        error: function(data) {
            hide_overLay(AJAX_ERR_MSG);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
<script>
```

`Backend`

```html
<?php
$action = $_POST ['action'];
if($action == 'print_file'){
    echo "Test 123";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.print();</script>";

}
?>
```

The output result is shown me like below the picture, this output got 2 errors, first is the top (red arrow) loading non-stop, second is no pop-up in the print dialog box :

[image: output 1]

I want the expected output like below the picture:

[image: output 2]

Comment: What are the errors? Or by errors do you mean bugs/unexpected results?

Comment: Error is no pop-up the print dialog box in the page

Comment: In the future, please use the terms "bug" or "unexpected result" to refer to issues like that. "Error" can often be confused with programming language errors.

Comment: Okay. Thank you point out.

Comment: So can you @GalaxyCat105 help me on this question?

Comment: also to stop the loading spinner, return the full correct html5 structured dom else the browser thinks your feeding in content till you call `myWindow.document.close()`

Comment: Thanks@LawrenceCherone. You are right. Then the pop-up the print dialog box in the page do you know how to solve it?